# I want to make my code global .I want to use same code 2-3 time one by one but its working together

Tags: jquery

i want to toggle a text but want to use it 2-3 places on same page.

```
$(".showdiv").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("active");

    if ($(this).text() == "+ Show More"){
     var sachin =  $('.transc_crosssell').removeClass("hidden");
     $(this).text("- Show Less");
     alert(sachin);
     }
    else {
       $(this).text("+ Show More");
       $('.transc_crosssell').addClass("hidden");
       }

});
```

but all toggle working together.Please tell me how to reslove that.i want one toggle should only if i click on that.

```
<div class="showdiv">+ Show More</div`>

<div class="transc_crosssell hidden">xyx text </div>
```

Comment: instead of targeting all divs with class "transc_crosssell". You need to target only one like this: $(this).next('.transc_crosssell').doStuff()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat divs wiich class `showdiv` and `transc_crossell` always as a pair, you can group them by wrapping with another `div`. If you do that, you'll be able to get corresponding `transc_crosssell` by doing

```
$(this).parent().children('.transc_crosssell');
```

Comment: @SachinRawal I'm glad it helped. I use this approach very often lately. But use it carefully, because with more complicated relations you could end up with many nested wrappers.